# My delete button actually doesn't delete anything ,, when i click on it it does nothing

Tags: php

```
<?php

$query = "select courses.id, courses.title, courses.category_id, courses.description, courses.start_date, courses.end_date, courses.image, courses.location, courses.published, course_category.title as category, trainers.name as trainer from courses 
LEFT JOIN course_category ON courses.category_id = course_category.id
LEFT JOIN trainers ON courses.trainer_id = trainers.id
order by courses.id DESC";

$courses = $traininovate->fetchAllData($query, $con);

if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
    $course_id = $_GET['delete']; // course id 

    $query = "DELETE FROM COURSES WHERE id = $course_id";
    $traininovate->deleteRow($query, $con);

    $query = "DELETE FROM open_attendance WHERE course_id = $course_id";
    $traininovate->deleteRow($query, $con);

    $query = "DELETE FROM course_materials WHERE course_id = $course_id";
    $traininovate->deleteRow($query, $con);

    $query = "DELETE FROM course_attendance WHERE course_id = $course_id";
    $traininovate->deleteRow($query, $con);

    $query = "DELETE FROM course_evaluation WHERE course_id = $course_id";
    $traininovate->deleteRow($query, $con); 

    header("location: courseslist.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Any error messages? Any checking for errors anywhere in the code you dont show us?

Comment: AA No,, i can post a screen shot if u want

Comment: https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Screenshot-2022-05-09-112658.png

Comment: WHat purpose does the initial SELECT query serve to this code

Comment: Show us a `var_dump($_GET)` please

Comment: No syntax error

Comment: It would also be useful to see the HTML form that is launching this code

Comment: alright my mistake

Comment: hi ahmed, welcome to stackoverflow. have you take a [tour] and learn [ask]? those being said, you need to narrow down the problem first. see if its originated from the html form not passing correct `course_id`. it can also be how you execute query, may we know what is this `deleteRow` function defined?

Comment: to be honest im not very good with codes im still learning ,, so i think i copied it from  a example code and some line from others and i used my database files names

Comment: Are you using the `mysqli_` or `PDO` extension to access your database? If you are not sure than show us the script the connects to the database

Comment: myqli . .......

Comment: To get errors out of PHP _even in a LIVE environment_ add these 4 lines **temporarily, while debugging**, to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.